# How to set up color of TableView, that we see after pull cells down

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to change the color of the TableView that we can see, when cells has been pulled down[image]

I have tried all sort of fields in table inspector and tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

I would like to highlight, I don't need to set up cell color, only tableview

Comment: Is that the UIRefreshControl backgroundColor?

Comment: @Don, I have tried  tableView.refreshControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red, but the result is the same. It is still white. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: Did you set it first? `tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`

Comment: Simply adding `self.tableView.backgroundColor = .red` in `viewDidLoad` should give the table view a red background, including the area above the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `backgroundView`, try this:

```
    tableView.backgroundView = UIView(frame: tableView.frame)
    tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
```